# Proving something is not strict stationary

Tags: stationarity

Let $W$  be a uniform distribution on $(0,\pi)$. Let $Z_t=\cos(tw)$. I know that $Z_t$ is a strict stationary but I have no idea how to prove this. Can someone show me how or give me some methods?

Comment: You might consider clicking the "edit" link to add a [ [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)] tag to this question. My first thought on how to approach: what does $\cos(tw)$ tell you about $\cos[(t-\theta)w]$?

Comment: How do you _know_ that $Z_t$ is a strictly stationary process? Did someone tell you this? Or did you read it in a book? If so, which one? Because it would seem to me that $Z_0 = \cos(W\times 0) = 1$ is a _constant_ (degenerate random variable) while $Z_1 = \cos(W\times 1) = \cos(W)$ is a _random variable_ that takes on values in $(-1,1)$. What this tells you about stationarity is left for you to determine.